# AppleScript - do JavaScript returns missing value

Tags: javascript, applescript

The below script is used to click on a button to load a date on our website, then get the value of that date.

It should then return that date value, which will be used in some comparisons later on.
However, when I log doJavaStuff and emptyDate, both come back as "(*missing value *)".
The *display dialog* for emptyDate also returns "msng".

Why isn't the result of the do JavaScript being returned?

I've looked at multiple articles and sources and tried multiple suggestions, but nothing has worked.
e.g. I tried setting the second line of the do JavaScript to a variable, and returning that variable, but that somehow made the AppleScript variable undefined.

I'm relatively new to AppleScript, so maybe I'm missing something obvious.

```
global emptyDue, serviceDate, doJavaStuff
set emptyDue to " "
set doJavaStuff to " "
set serviceDate to "2021-11-30"

on isEmptyDue()
    
    tell application "Safari" to tell document 1
        set doJavaStuff to do JavaScript
        "document.getElementById('trgUseNext').click(); #clicks button to load date.
            document.getElementById('inspDate').value;" --gets the value of date
        return doJavaStuff
    end tell
    
end isEmptyDue

set emptyDate to isEmptyDue()
display dialog emptyDate

log doJavaStuff
log emptyDate
```

Comment: You use either `/*...*/` or `//...` for JS comments, `#` is more so python.

Comment: @gurkensaas Thank you. My script still doesn't work.

Comment: It is not really possible to test your code, since you didn't provide the website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to duplicate your problem using an element that happens to be on this StackOverFlow page (`post-id`), using this simplified version of your script:

```
on isEmptyDue()
    tell application "Safari" to tell document 1
        set doJavaStuff to do JavaScript
        "document.getElementById('post-id').value"
        return doJavaStuff
    end tell
end isEmptyDue

set emptyDate to isEmptyDue()
display dialog emptyDate
```

The return value is, as you noted, “msng”.

The problem appears to be that AppleScript is perfectly happy to have nothing but quoted text on its own line, and is *also* perfectly happy to run `do JavaScript` with no script. That is, the code as you’ve presented it doesn’t run any JavaScript: it calls `do JavaScript` with nothing, and then the next line is a string of text that AppleScript ignores.

If I combine the lines so that they are one line instead of two, `display dialog emptyDate` displays the expected 8-digit value of element `post-id` on this StackOverFlow page (found by viewing the source).

```
on isEmptyDue()
    tell application "Safari" to tell document 1
        set doJavaStuff to do JavaScript "document.getElementById('post-id').value"
        return doJavaStuff
    end tell
end isEmptyDue

set emptyDate to isEmptyDue()
display dialog emptyDate
```

That was oddly difficult to track down because neither of the “mistakes” provided an obvious error: `do JavaScript` without any text is not an error—instead, it returns a cryptic string, “msng”, which I suspect but do not know stands for “missing”—and a string on its own on a line is not an error either. So it looks like it’s doing something and not working, instead of not doing anything and not working.

Comment: You, sir, have saved me hours of head-scratching, thank you so much! Seriously appreciate how much you put into figuring this out. Thank you! :D